# Beautiful Soup output none while parsing URLs

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have written a function to parse the article URLs from the [archives](http://archives.ndtv.com/articles/2020-05.html) of [NDTV News](http://archives.ndtv.com/articles/2020-05.html). It returns None output instead of a list of URLs. Why its returning None?

```
    def parse_ndtv_archive_links():
        url_count=0
        links = []
        url = makeURL()
        while (url_count < len(url)):
            page=requests.get(url[url_count]).text
            soup=BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
            section=soup.find('div', id="main-content")
            for a in section.findAll('li'):
                href=a.get('href')
                links.append(href) 
            url_count += 1
        return list(links) 
print(parse_ndtv_archive_links())
```

So the parse function loop on each day archives of NDTV and fetches the URLs. So the `makeURL()` function generates a list of archive URLs for a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in your variable `a` is not stored tag `<a>` but tag `<li>` and tag `<li>` doesn't have attribute `href`. One way to solve this is like this.

```
for li in section.findAll('li'):
    href=li.a.get('href')
    links.append(href)
```

Edit: it separates days now

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['http://archives.ndtv.com/articles/2020-05.html']
for url in urls:
    current_day = 1
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    days = soup.find('div', {'id': 'main-content'}).find_all('ul')
    links = {day_num: [] for day_num in range(1, len(days)+1)}
    for day in days:
        for li in day.findAll('li'):
            href = li.a.get('href')
            links[current_day].append(href)
        current_day += 1
print(links)
```

Result is stored in dictionary `links` where key is number of day in month and value is list of links. This dictionary contains only days for **one** month, if you wish to store data for more than one month you will need to tweek this code a little bit.

Comment: `for li in section.findAll('li'):`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'`
Still same error.

Comment: Then your `makeURL()` function is not working right. I tested my solution with hardcoded urls in `url` variable and it works.

Comment: And you could said that you have that error from the start, not that your program works without errors just returning None instead of links.

Comment: Thankyou :) Its working but its crawling the complete month article URLs. Is there any way to get the article URLs of a particular day let say 5th May 2020 or any period?

Comment: I will edit my answer, if it solves your problem you can mark this question as answer